# Would moving in with an indirectly lower ranked coworker be conflict of interest?

Tags: communication, relationships, conflict-of-interest, hierarchy

I work in the office for a college department which handles both counseling (the psychiatric kind) and disability services. Technically, they should be two seperate departments and in the past were, before merging a while back because the college decided they weren't important enough to justify two departments. I'm considered full-time staff, while my friend and potential future roommate, is part-time staff. In the campus-wide hierarchy, I would be considered higher ranked, but my position has no actual leadership or influence over his position.

We have been friends longer than we've worked together (I had no influence/control over the hiring process and our supervisors were aware we knew each other) and have no romantic relationship nor interest in one. It would strictly be for financial reasons (we both accrued debt during 2020 due to COVID that we want to squash down).

Would it be a conflict of interest to move in with him even though we are not within the same department (same office space however) but where my influence is miniscule? If so, is it significant enough that it could put our jobs at risk of dramatic change, such as department changes? (Which come with a risk of being no longer "essential enough" to justify with the current COVID impacts, whereas right now we're protected with admin fearing ADA violation.) If it's safe to proceed, how would it be best to notify my boss?

To add some additional thoughts:

- Even though I know it can't be used for a conflict of interest, the part where I always get stuck is the fact we are classified at two different levels. (Even then, when you extrapolate my hourly rate from my salary, we have a difference of $0.20/hour.)
- The college is also rife with much more blatant examples of favoritism or people related to each other who have much more obvious conflicts of interest; most of the upper administration are long-term friends or else have business partnerships (and are frequently appointed/hired because of this), and one of the two women in payroll has two children who work at the college.

  - I don't claim to know what's on file with HR for these cases, or what their department leads have outlined as boundaries, so for all I know they're under extreme safeguards to ensure foul play can't happen. (*Based on how I've heard other friends in staff complain about it, however, I have my doubts that it's regulated...*)

Comment: I couldn't find it in your question, but what is the reason for moving in? (Relationship, financial, ...)

Comment: How can this be a conflict or interest if you don't have any actual power over her?

Comment: What does your staff handbook/conditions of employment/whatever say about office relationships?

Comment: This seems like an easy thing to ask Jackson or the overall HR department. If you and Oswald have been dating and it's reached the living-together stage, your conflict of interest, if any, already exists. If you need to replace your current roomie (or Oswald does) as a rent-saving approach, that's a different question. An edit would help: it's weird we have two pages on how your department works but nothing on precisely who you want to move in with or more importantly why.

Comment: Honestly, I'm exhausted from reading this question, and yet we don't know who it is you're wanting to cohabitate with. Are either of you the other's boss? If not then there's no conflict of interest.

Comment: Welcome new user.  I would truly urge you to simply edit the question to a max length of one of your paragraphs.  (At the absolute limit, two fo those.)  Quite simply: on this site, long questions get closed.  Good luck!

Comment: Important question: are you male or female? If you and Oswald are both male, you might be able to go ahead with it anyway regardless, and then pull the "discrimination against LGBT" card if any of the staff act against you for it, especially given the described behavior of some of the (presumably heterosexual) senior staff.

Comment: From reading your question, you seem very organized and detail-oriented in a positive way. Sometimes being careful to examine all the details and think about all the aspects of a problem can make it harder to make the right decision. What is your concern exactly with moving in with a coworker? How other people will perceive it? If it will cause  conflicts at work when you look over their time card? It might help people answer your question if you could distill your worries into one main concern about how your living situation might affect your work situation.

Comment: The relationships with Jackson and Regina are not particularly important here.  Literally all of that could be covered by "We work in the same office, officially under different bosses."  The fact that you occasionally give him tasks (and that he's expected to carry them out) and the bit about the excel spreadsheet are still pertinent.  What your relationship with Oswald actually is is *very* important, and you seem to have dodged that to the point of not actually admitting that he's the one you're thinking about moving in with.  There may well be a problem here, but cohabitation isn't it.

Comment: VTC because it's very hard to understand what is being asked. All I get is you're moving in with someone which I assume is based on a romantic relationship with someone you work with but not directly in control of.

Comment: Is there a way you can rephrase the question such that the "other" people are not included? Simply state your relationship of the person you're moving in with and then state your relationship with the person at the work place. For example, "I am a manager and X is working at a different department, and we're in a relationship and I plan to move in with him/her. Is there a conflict of relationship?" Then it can be a simple yes/no question without the needless other people in this story.

Comment: This question isn't going to get a correct answer. All you're going to get is opinions since nobody knows your workplace policies.

Comment: What does your employee manual say?